# How is the callback from a resource owner processed in HWIOAuthBundle?

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

I am trying to understand how HWIOauthBUndle works. I can see how the initial authorization request to a resource owner is built and made.

I do not see however, how a callback made from a resource owner triggers any controller/action in my application (which it most obviously does, though).

When following the generally available instructions, the callback will be made to something like `<path to my app>/check-[resourceOwner]`, e.g. `http://www.example.com/oauth/check-facebook`.

In my `routing.yml` file, I put

```
facebook_login:
    pattern: /oauth/check-facebook
```

I don't see how any controller is associated with that route, so what actually happens when a callback is made to my application?

Answer (score 0):

The authentication provider system is one of the more complicated features.  You will probably want to read through here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Callbacks are handled through a request listener.  Specifically:

```
namespace HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Http\Firewall\OAuthListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AbstractAuthenticationListener;

class OAuthListener extends AbstractAuthenticationListener
{
public function requiresAuthentication(Request $request)
{
    // Check if the route matches one of the check paths
    foreach ($this->checkPaths as $checkPath) {
        if ($this->httpUtils->checkRequestPath($request, $checkPath)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)
{
    // Lots of good stuff here
```

How checkPaths get's initialized and how all the calls are made would require a very long explanation.  But the authentication provider chapter will get you going.